# Local Variables in DMN?

Tags: kie, dmn, feel-language

Can we initialize local variables inside a dmn using FEEL/Literal expression

```
if (somecondition) then {
  newVar=newVal
}else { }

if(newVar==someVal) then {..}
else {}
```

Can we initialize local variables and use them the way it is done in OOP? I need to utilize the local variable, I do not intent to use BKM here.

Answer (score 2):

DMN FEEL is an *expression* language and as such it does *not* have statements, specifically variable assignment statements.

> Can we initialize local variables and use them the way it is done in OOP?

This is indeed a typical statement in java such as

```java
String name = "John Doe";
```

and being a statement is not available in the FEEL *expression* language.

That said, in ***special scenarios***, you might use an helpful trick of inlining a FEEL context to mimic similar behaviour.

Something ~like:

```
{
  newVar: if (somecondition) then ... else ... ,
  result: if (newVar=someVal) then ... else
}.result
```

For example:

```
{
  newVar: if (a number > 0) then "pos" else "neg" ,
  result: if (newVar="pos") then "positive" else "negative"
}.result
```

if supplied with `a number` would result in the value `"positive"` or `"negative"` FEEL string, with no trace of the `newVar` or the `"pos"` or `"neg"` in the final result.

Demo:
[image]